# In iOS coordinate system, is the given location in pixels or in another specific unit?

Tags: ios, coordinate-systems

In my application, the user can manually place some UIViews inside a UIImageView. While processing the result, I noticed that UIViews Location (X, Y) or Width or even Height are floats so I'm having some floats values like for example: 100.22233

I don't understand how it could be possible because I need to have those values in pixels, is there any way to convert those values to pixels?

Thanks.

Comment: you must be looking at the wrong value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIView properties such as `frame` and `bounds` provide coordinates in points, not pixels. One point is one pixel on a non-retina screen; one point is four pixels (2x2 rect) on a retina screen.

If you want integer values for your coordinates, you can truncate float values like this:

```
CGFloat xLocation = (NSInteger)100.22233 + (CGFloat)0.0f;
```

If you instead want to round to the nearest integer (101 when starting with 100.8, as you suggested in comments), you can add 0.5 to the float before rounding it, like this:

```
CGFloat xLocation = (NSInteger)(100.8 + 0.5) + (CGFloat)0.0f;
```

Comment: by doing this, I will not loose 0.22233? let's say that I'm having 100.8, using 100 pixels will make me loose almost 1pixel, no?

Comment: Yes, this is truncation. If you instead want to round to the nearest integer value, a standard technique is to add 0.5 before truncating. I'll update my answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

The units are points, which translate to 1pt == 1px in non-retina and 1pt == 2px in retina.

If you want integral values, you can use `CGRectIntegral` like:

```
view.frame = CGRectIntegral(view.frame)
```

Answer (score -3):

Points Versus Pixels
In iOS, all coordinate values and distances are specified using floating-point values in units referred to as points. The measurable size of a point varies from device to device and is largely irrelevant. The main thing to understand about points is that they provide a fixed frame of reference for drawing.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/CoordinateSystem.html

YOu can go through the above documentation in detail

Comment: You plagiarized the first paragraph [from iPad Application Development for Dummies](http://books.google.com/books?id=uxJaSnf1f1IC&pg=PT277&lpg=PT277&dq=%22all+coordinate+values+and+distances+are+specified+using+floating-point+values+in+units+referred+to+as+points.+The+measurable+size+of+a+point+varies+from+device+to+device%22&source=bl&ots=CIN8A6p4-r&sig=UMpf9nPKlBDXxSjvbkjO8xiGGGM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f-MQU9PzEsPwoATg1IK4Dg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage). Please attribute your source when you do such things, and put quoted content in blockquotes.